# JQuery easyui datagrid ajax json data rendering issue

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-easyui

I know the default json string format for datagrid is like this:

```
{'total':100,'rows':[{id:'1',name:'Jason'},{id:'2',name:'Liam'}]};
```

however our vendor changed their product's API which made the returning string becomes like this:

```
{"pager":{"recordCount":100},'list':[{id:'1',name:'Jason'},{id:'2',name:'Liam'}]};
```

'cause the format was changed, so that the datagrid plugin doesn't work properly any more, I tried let them change back but for some reasons they can't do that, the only way is to made some changes with datagrid plugin.

I saw there is a method called '**loader**' in the method list, but I'm not sure whether it helps or not, could someone can give me a suggestion or an advice ?

Thank you.

here is the datagrid reference link : http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#

Comment: I try to parsing json with format that you said causing the problem, but it's not problem. can you post more code and let us know the version of your jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a simple converter function to get the new JSON back to the old way:

```
function convertJSON(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    var newJSON = {};
    newJSON["total"] = data.pager.recordCount;
    newJSON['rows'] = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
        newJSON['rows'][i] = data.list[i];
    }

    return newJSON;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7q3kx/

Comment: the problem is I don't know where to intercept the JSON strings, there is a Loader function proposed by that plugin, but I'm not able to find an example case to explain the process.